# Pandas multilevel columns dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename, multi-index

I have a df with 48 columns and i want to rename them on two levels as in the dict below:

```
{'A': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
 'B': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
 'C': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
 'D': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']}
```

i would like to get something like this:
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfNDb.png)

Comment: Please show the df you want to rename. Have you tried searching for this?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing both the data and the code produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you. **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you visit this [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html), and read the **see also** section, you find 4 ways to build multiindex. Given your input which can be easily converted into a `pd.DataFrame`, `pd.MultiIndex.from_frame` should take the least coding effort.

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(pd.DataFrame(dictionary).melt())
```